# spring log4j initilaization vs custom log4j initilaization

Tags: java, spring, log4j

We are modifying a java web application based on struts to spring framework. We were using 'log4j' for logging. It was initialized through a startup servlet in web.xml, which will call
 `PropertyConfigurator.configure(propertiesfile)`

It was working fine.But the confusion is whether to change this initilization to spring specific initilization through `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` .

I need to know is there **any advantage of using spring's configuration over traditional way?**

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring and using the `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` you could use placeholders in the configuration name.

So something like this

```
<param-value>file://etc/conf/your-app/${environment:default}/log4j.config</param-value>
```

No if there would be a property called `environment` in your environment variables, JVM properties or servlet-context it would be replaced, else 'default' would be used.

This advantage is what you get from the spring version and the fact that you can drop your own custom servlet (a little less code to maintain, Remember: **the best maintainable code is code not written**).